# Customize tool panel in ag grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Is it possible to customise and extend ag grid tool panel to add custom features which are not provided by the original tool panel?

Like in my case , I want to add some dropdowns as input filters in the tool panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an entirely new toolpanel, but you cannot extend the prebuilt toolpanels.

Comment: It's a shame, but this seems to be most correct as of ag-grid v22. I really wanted to add my own buttons to the existing column filter tool panel

Answer (score 0):

Now its possible with [19.0 version](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-component/)

> Custom Tool Panel Components can be included into the grids Side Bar. Implement these when you require more Tool Panels to meet your application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add filter dropdowns by adding a filterParams property to your columnDefs to the column you want.

```
this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 150,
        filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
        filterParams: {
          values: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
        }
      },
]
```

You can see here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/